# Experiencing slowness while running automation in mac M1 terminal using chromeDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, apple-m1

**Description:**
I've encountered an issue in our Selenium automation running on Mac M1. The error we're consistently facing is `Net::timeout` or similar timeouts during the automation execution. It's crucial to note that these errors aren't indicative of code failures rather, actions couldn't be performed due to slowness in the automation window.

Automation fails when the waiting time to perform actions or load pages exceeds its limit. The slowness we observe is not limited to automation execution alone; it also affects the chrome window opened via automation. Even manual actions within this particular window experience significant delays.

**Additional Notes:**
The issue is specific to `Mac M1`, Intel chip Macs do not seem to be affected.
Normal chrome windows and tabs, used for regular surfing, do not exhibit this slowness issue.

I have also noticed that my chrome arch Version is `120.0.6099.234 (Official Build) (arm64)` and the window opened via automation has `Version 120.0.6099.234 (Official Build) (x86_64 translated)`. Will this be the reason for slowness?

Are there known solutions or workarounds to address the slowness in automation execution and the opened chrome window?
Is there any specific configuration or optimization needed for Selenium or ChromeDriver on Mac M1?

Any insights or assistance would help me!

Comment: Face the same issue